# Filter RadGrid Column Based on Its Text not Value

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a text box which I manage its text changing event to filter the RadGrid:

```
private void txtJob_TextChanging(object sender, TextChangingEventArgs e)
{
    this.gridCustomers.Columns["JobColumn"].FilterDescriptor = new FilterDescriptor
    {
        Operator = FilterOperator.Contains,
        Value = txtJob.Text
    };
}
```

I change JobColumn Text using CellFormatting Event:

```
private void gridCustomers_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Name == "JobColumn")
        e.CellElement.Text = db.tblJobs.First(x => x.JobID == Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[9].Value.ToString())).JobName;
}
```

I'm replacing Job ID with its Job Name in JobColumn, in that Text Box which I filtering RadGrid I'm searching for Job Name which is visible in RadGrid Now, but it will filter based on Job ID which is the default value before replacing.
So How can I filter a RadGrid Column based on its Text not Value?

For more information I'm binding a table like this to my girdview:

```
int JobID
nvarchar(10) Name
nvarchar(100) Address
.
.
.
```

And I have a table named Jobs like this:

```
int JobID
nvarchar(30) JobName
.
.
.
```

I need to get JobID from table one and in data binding (cell Formatting) replace the ID with its JobName in Jobs table.
Why I'm not selecting new and joining two table? because in that case I have not a grid view which can be edited easily, I must use Virtual Gird which is not my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to hack the system. The correct approach in your case is to use GridVieWComboBoxColumn, which can be bound and DisplayMember and ValueMember to be specified. It also has FilterMode property to determine which field to use for filtering.

Read more [GridViewComboBoxColumn | Telerik UI for WinForms Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/columns/column-types/gridviewcomboboxcolumn)

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample to get you started

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        DataTable mainTable = new DataTable();
        mainTable.Columns.Add("JobID", typeof(int));
        mainTable.Columns.Add("Name");
        mainTable.Columns.Add("Address");

        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            mainTable.Rows.Add(rand.Next(1,4), "Name " + i, "Address " + i);
        }

        DataTable jobsTable = new DataTable();
        jobsTable.Columns.Add("JobID", typeof(int));
        jobsTable.Columns.Add("JobName");

        jobsTable.Rows.Add(1, "ABC ");
        jobsTable.Rows.Add(2, "DFG");
        jobsTable.Rows.Add(3, "XCV");

        radGridView1 = new RadGridView() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill };
        this.Controls.Add(radGridView1);
        radGridView1.EnableFiltering = true;

        radGridView1.DataSource = mainTable; //this will create all columns

        radGridView1.Columns.Remove(radGridView1.Columns["JobId"]);

        GridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboCol.DataSource = jobsTable;
        comboCol.FieldName = "JobID"; //the name of the field in the main table to look for
        comboCol.DisplayMember = "JobName"; //you want to see job names not ids
        comboCol.ValueMember = "JobID";
        comboCol.FilteringMode = GridViewFilteringMode.DisplayMember;
        radGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, comboCol);
    }

    private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radGridView1.Columns["JobID"].FilterDescriptor = new FilterDescriptor
        {
            Operator = FilterOperator.Contains,
            Value = "B"
        };
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to use Custom Filtering to filter rows based on cell's texts not values?

Comment: and what about dirty one?

Comment: Use what I suggested above with the combo column.

Comment: The problem is that The Display Member should be set on Cell formatting, because it is located on another table.

Comment: CellFormatting is used just to apply cell appearance modifications. Provide an example of your data and precisely what you want to achieve.

Comment: Me too. I hope you can use this and accommodate it for your needs.

Comment: GREAT MAN, Works like a charm ;)